# How to bind only years to dropdown list using jquery

Tags: jquery

Am new to jquery , i need to bind only years to dropdownlist using jquery.But its not binding to dropdownlist.Please anyone suggest me...

In jquery

```
  function addYear() {
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            $("#PassedYear").append( $("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", currentYear)
                    .text(currentYear)


            );
            currentYear++;

        }
    }

    addYear();
```

In View

```
         <td>
             Certification Name
         </td>
         <td>
             Passed Year
         </td>
     </tr>

@for (var j =0; j < Model.EducationDetailsFields.Certifications.Count; j++)

{


     <tr>

                    <td>
                        <div id="Certified" class="disable">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EducationDetailsFields.Certifications[j].CertificationName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EducationDetailsFields.Certifications[j].CertificationName)
                        </div>
                    </td>

                     <td>
                        <div  class="disable">
                          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EducationDetailsFields.Certifications[j].PassedYear, new SelectList(Model.EducationDetailsFields.Certifications, "Passedyear", "Passedyear"), "--Select--", new {id="PassedYear" })


                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EducationDetailsFields.Certifications[j].PassedYear)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>



}



      </table>
```

During page load 3 dropdown should be loaded with years ...here first dropdown is loaded ,rest is not..how to add for loop variable j to Dropdown id..Can any one please have a look on it

Comment: What result are you getting and what are you expecting? The code you posted works fine for me.

Comment: You need to call `addYear()` once element `#year` is available in the DOM. So use instead to call it on document ready: `$(addYear);`  e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/0xnqdy35/

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply..please have a look on edited post...give a suggestions for that